# How to construct json that has dynamic values and multi level arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, object

trying to figure out on how to construct json that has dynamic values that I am getting from data-attributes. Also would like to do it with multi-level array inside the object.

example:

HTML:

```
<div data-color="red" data-type="honda">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function constructJson(el) {
  var obj = {},
    numberOfCars = 1,
    carColor = el.data('color'),
    carType = el.data('honda'),
    jsonObj = new obj();

  jsonObj.color = carColor;
  jsonObj.type = carType;
}
```

Hoping to create json that looks like:

```
{
    "package": [{
        "numberOfCars": 1,
        "Car": [{
            "color": "red",
            "type": "Honda"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Is it constricted to only color and type or are there any more variables that are dynamic??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this method to

```
function constructJson(el) {
  return {
    "package": [{
        "numberOfCars": 1,
        "Car": [{
            "color": el.data('color'),
            "type": el.data('honda')
        }]
    }]
  }
}
```

this method will now return the object to you which has the required values populated from `el`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming color and type are the dynamic variables, check this fiddle here which creates and prints the json object : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/L1uvzqbz/)

```js
function constructJson(el) {
  numberOfCars = 1;
  carColor = el.data('color');
  carType = el.data('type');
  var jsonObj = new Object();
  jsonObj.package = [];
  jsonObj.package.push({
    numberOfCars: numberOfCars
  });
  jsonObj.package.push({
    Car: [{
      color: carColor,
      type: carType
    }]
  });
  $('#print').text(JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, 2));
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  var el = $("#car-div");
  constructJson(el);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-color="red" data-type="honda" id="car-div">
</div>
<pre id="print">
</pre>
```